Does anyone know what the symbol or footprint is supposed to look like for this toggle switch?
I'm trying to make a circuit diagram on Eagle and I can't find the symbol or footprint for this particular toggle switch called 5646MAB (first pic). I would custom make it myself on Eagle but I have no clue what it should even look like.
If you know what it's supposed to look like or even know another switch with a similar pin layout, please lmk!
The second photo is something I saw randomly online but I'm not sure if it's right



If any of the answers given solved your problem its considered good practice to mark it as accepted


I can't find the symbol or footprint for this particular toggle switch

The component in your question is not a PCB-mount switch so a footprint is kinda meaningless. From the switch's pins you can run wires to your PCB, so you can place a few number of pads wherever you want on your PCB.
Alternatively, you can select a PCB-mount type (i.e. surface-mount or through hole) from here, for example. Some of them contain EDA (electronic design automation) models available for downloading. Or you can manually create your own footprint based on the dimensions given in the datasheet.

The second photo is something I saw randomly online but I'm not sure if it's right

It's the schematic symbol so it can be used in the schematic design, not the PCB layout.

This toggle switch is labeled "panel mount" which means it's made for direct wiring. What you want is a "through hole" or "surface mount" type not a "panel mount".
While you can find many footprints (of wildly varying quiality) for most surface mount and through hole components, learning how to create your own is always a good thing because then you're responsible for the quality yourself (and can choose to make them to match each other).
Often you'll find recommended footprints in the datasheet from the supplier. Use them as guide, they're not gospel.
The most important thing for a home project on footprints is distance of hole and size of holes. Don't take the recommended copper area from your software but make the copper area big. For hand soldering, oblong pads are often better than round ones.
Function wise, those switches are mostly the same. You can see it nicely in the linked datasheet on the DigiKey page:

The dual pole switch you have just has the same side by side.
If you find a footprint, always carefully check if the hole sizes, distances and pad sizes fit your needs.

Footprint
The switch you linked is not really meant to be mounted to a circuit board - it's got a panel mount thread, and solder lug terminals, that implies it's meant for soldering wires to the legs.
A PCB mount toggle switch would have longer, narrower pins and typically some support pins. (Not used for signal switching but for mechanical support)
Think something like this:

source: Some random image online. https://www.salecom.com/en/product/t8013-s20.html 
Mounting the type of switch that you linked to a circuit board will expose the solder joints to mechanical stress every time you toggled the switch.
If on the other hand you insist on mounting this to a circuit board, the dimensions you need to take into consideration are from the datasheet:


datasheet:https://www.apem.com/medias/5000M.pdf
Symbol
The switch you linked is a Double Pole, Double Throw switch, meaning it has two sets of contacts, where one is normally closed and one is normally open. The symbol will have to be adapted to what your (or eagle) library style is, but such a switch is represented with this style of symbol:

source: wikipedia https://no.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fil:DPDT-symbol.svg
